# jQuery - Fade in next step form

Tags: jquery, forms

I can't figure this one out or find anything related. So any help would be appreciated.

So basic form inputs hidden except the first. When user fills the first input, the next one will fade in. Something in manner of:

```
input each
val placeholder
if !empty or !placeholder
find next input fade in
```

How can I write that? I cant seem to manage to get it working no matter what I try.

Comment: Could you show us some code with what you tried already?

Comment: have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put an `onBlur` event and check if the value is non empty

```js
$(function() {
  $('input').on('blur', function() {
    if($(this).val() != '') {
      $(this).next('input').fadeIn('slow');
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" />
<input type="text" hidden />
<input type="text" hidden/>
<input type="text" hidden/>
```

Comment: THANK YOU! PERFECT

Comment: Glad to help. You can just add some of your approacsh in your question that will prevent you from getting downvotes